# Lightning examples

Tags: lightning-design-system, chrome, selenium

I have been writing Java/Chromedriver/Selenium code to SQA some Salesforce (apptus) pages.
The project manager says they are going to Lighning in several months.  I am trying to get a jump start on figuring out lightning and what changes I may have to make.  I was looking for some sites already developed in Lightning that are open to the public, that I can look at with Chrome Inspector.  Can anyone suggest any?

Comment: By the way, these are agreement documents and amendment documents

Answer (score 0):

You can sign up for your own personal developer environment at [developer.salesforce.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/). You'll be able to use Lightning in that Developer Edition org and build whatever tools and experiments you need to prepare for your project.

Comment: I actually tried but it wanted me to agree to the conditions.  I have no problem doing that.  Just I could not find the box to check to agree.